# Как добавлять в "избранное" по нажатию кнопки в tableview?

Tags: ios, swift

Всем доброго времени суток
Может кто нибудь показать как сделать такую вещь
Я нажимаю на кнопку в `tableview` и он сохраняет в `UserDefaults` мою строку на которой я нажал на кнопку
Хочу реализовать страничку "избранное", ток вот не знаю как сделать

Comment: Добрый день, а что конкретно не получается?

Comment: Не получается именно то что не могу понять что добавлять в `UserDefaults`
Массив со всеми элементами или `id` строки?
Так же не знаю как это все в кнопке прописать, как сохранять в `UserDefaults` я знаю, имеется в виду как дать кнопке понять что нужно созранить именно эту ячейку

Comment: Покажите вид tableView и где находится кнопка, и что вы подразумеваете под id строки, пока что не очень понятно, что вам требуется...

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку никакого кода в вопросе не представлено, опишу просто один из вариантов реализации

- Для начала нужно как-то уникально идентифицировать элементы, которые вы будете выводить - если это статический неизменяемый набор данных, то можно использовать порядковый номер элемента, а если динамический, то нужно создать уникальные идентификаторы самостоятельно например путем генерации хэша или используя id из базы данных, если данные берутся из нее
- Данные загружаете в массив, допустим `data`, если выводятся строки, то это будет массив содержащий структуру с полями скажем `id`, `text`
- Далее в кастомном классе ячейки для таблицы, содержащем вашу кнопку добавления в избранное, добавляете свойство для хранения id, допустим `cellId`
- При заполнении таблицы в методе `cellForRow(at:)` используете `data[indexPath.row].id` для сохранения индекса в `cellId`
- В классе с `tableView` создаете массив для хранения индексов избранных ячеек, например `favouriteIds`
- При нажатии на кнопку избранного в конкретной ячейке добавляете значение, сохраненное в `cellId`, в массив `favouriteIds`
- Полученный массив сохраняете в настройки, например как показано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179668/how-to-save-and-read-array-of-array-in-nsuserdefaults-in-swift)
- При повторном заполнении общей таблицы достаете сохраненный массив из настроек и проверяете индексы в нем - если индекс в массиве есть, значит как-то выделяем кнопку избранного в ячейке, а на экране избранного соответственно из полного списка выводим только избранные индексы

А еще лучше использовать для всего этого базу данных с автогенерацией уникальных id и полем favourite (1/0), куда и сохранять статус каждой записи в таблице